# Exclude a column from DbContext using ASP.NET MVC and EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following model:

```
public class Movie
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [Display(Name = "Release date")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}")]
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Genre { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(1, 20)]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Compare("Email")]
    public string ConfirmEmail
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

and Db context:

```
public class MovieDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
}
```

and my table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Movies] (
    [Id]          INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Title]       NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [ReleaseDate] DATETIME       NOT NULL,
    [Genre]       NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [Price]       DECIMAL (6, 2) NOT NULL,
    [Email]       NVARCHAR (100) DEFAULT ('') NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

As you see, I added a new property called `ConfirmEmail` attached to `Movie` model. But I didn't add to table and I don't want to.

When run application, an error is occured:

Unknown column name `ConfirmEmail`.

**Does it is possible to exclude that `ConfirmEmail` from context ?**

It is just used as parameter to be compared to `Email` property.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [NotMappedAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.notmappedattribute)

```
[NotMapped]
public string ConfirmEmail {get;set;}
```